# Ordenar entradas de un dataFrame grande en base a dos columnas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datos, ordenar

Tengo un dataframe de 735000 filas y 6 columnas.

Esta ordenados aleatoriamente y me gustaría ordenarlo por índice de paciente ***patientId*** (cada paciente tiene un número asignado, por ejemplo 1562 y aparece X veces a lo largo del dataFrame) y por fecha de la entrada ***dateTime*** (se han tomado datos de los mismos pacientes cada x tiempo)

como podría hacerlo?